# Installing rewrite extension on IIS - possible risk?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

We have a number of existing php web applications, running on a Windows Server. We are going to add an application that has been built with CodeIgniter. In order to hide index.php from the url's, we need to activate the rewrite extension on IIS. Will this in any way effect the existing applications that don't need any rewrite rules?

Comment: Maybe this is a question for the sysadmin Stack Exchange? https://serverfault.com/